# Redirect Loop with Heroku and Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app runs fine locally, but when I push to Heroku, in Firefox it says "The page isn't redirecting properly" (i.e. a 302 error).

Running `heroku logs` results in a bunch of requests like this:

```
2015-06-02T21:30:26.556750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.mydomainname.com request_id=a0cb3aa2-af7c-431a-9cc4-a237e551ae0a fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=13ms status=302 bytes=499
2015-06-02T21:30:27.761039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.mydomainname.com request_id=32026d7d-2167-4058-8ef6-8ebd15af7460 fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=499
2015-06-02T21:30:27.914344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.mydomainname.com request_id=2087a90c-fd56-4d14-b630-9c92fda30c80 fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=499
```

When I run the "Network" option under Firefox's Developer section, it continuously shows that it is alternating between the domain with and without www.  For example:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
www.domain.com
domain.com
```

etc.

I am using a custom domain name but have it set up exactly how my other apps that are working are set up, so I don't *think* it is a DNS issue as far as how the setup goes.  Also, when I visit the "myappname.herokuapp.com" URL, it immediately redirects to heroku.com for some reason.  Not sure why.  I ran the "Production Check" and it passes the "DNS configuration" section.

I realize that I have not provided a bunch of information here (not sure what else to provide), but any ideas on what I could look into next?

**EDIT:** Today it is saying this prior to the redirect code posted earlier:

```
2015-06-03T14:38:14.651296+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from up to down
2015-06-03T14:38:17.135688+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774095+00:00 app[web.2]: [2015-06-03 14:38:17] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774101+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774103+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774104+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774105+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774106+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:35:in `run'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774108+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774109+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774110+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774111+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774113+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774114+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774115+00:00 app[web.2]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774117+00:00 app[web.2]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774118+00:00 app[web.2]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774147+00:00 app[web.2]: [2015-06-03 14:38:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-06-03T14:38:17.774124+00:00 app[web.2]: [2015-06-03 14:38:17] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-06-03T14:38:17.828035+00:00 app[web.2]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-06-03T14:38:17.828041+00:00 app[web.2]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:4223
2015-06-03T14:38:17.828043+00:00 app[web.2]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-06-03T14:38:17.828045+00:00 app[web.2]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-06-03T14:38:17.828046+00:00 app[web.2]: Exiting
2015-06-03T14:38:18.624457+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 143
```

**EDIT 2:** I re-cloned the repository into a different directory and then ran `heroku create`, `git push heroku master`, and then `heroku run rake db:migrate`.  I did this to eliminate any possible DNS issues.  The log now says:

```
2015-06-03T15:55:51.082260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lit-inlet-1933.herokuapp.com request_id=2cd494b9-8f93-4270-b8db-e1dda9a6ab4a fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-03T15:55:51.274766+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lit-inlet-1933.herokuapp.com request_id=78128ada-cb90-4580-8102-be756ec7b7cc fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-03T15:55:53.861456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lit-inlet-1933.herokuapp.com request_id=6d89785d-1b00-4b40-8984-15dbbe5e994f fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This shows 2 crashes to the root url "/" and 2 crashes on /favicon.ico.  Based on the favicon.ico, I removed any favicons from the root page as a test.  Now the app is behaving similarly to the earlier one: It immediately redirects to heroku.com instead of loading the page and the logs says:

```
2015-06-03T16:00:42.804253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-03T16:00:48.568268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 25258 -e production`
2015-06-03T16:00:57.769255+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-03 16:00:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-06-03T16:00:57.769284+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-03 16:00:57] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-06-03T16:00:57.769643+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-06-03 16:00:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=25258
2015-06-03T16:00:58.321124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-03T16:01:00.754258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=lit-inlet-1933.herokuapp.com request_id=8664d409-5542-4bee-914d-00639c08c2d0 fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=174ms status=302 bytes=501
```

The root URL is very simple.  There is a welcome_controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :index

  def index    
  end
end
```

and the view is:

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> Task Clash</h1>
    <p>A ridiculously simple and easy-to-use CRM/Time Tracking tool aimed at small businesses!</p>
    <p><%= link_to "Create Account", new_account_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %></p>
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 3**: I added rails_12factor to my Gemfile and now get this:

```
2015-06-03T19:37:48.713189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.taskclash.com request_id=c0dfd7ac-233c-4be9-a155-57b66f9a84cb fwd="173.27.229.45" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=435
2015-06-03T19:37:48.700898+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 173.27.229.45 at 2015-06-03 19:37:48 +0000
2015-06-03T19:37:48.710826+00:00 app[web.1]:   Account Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["subdomain", "www"]]
2015-06-03T19:37:48.711577+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :load_schema rendered or redirected
2015-06-03T19:37:48.711704+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
2015-06-03T19:37:48.703333+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TasksController#index as HTML
2015-06-03T19:37:48.711291+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://taskclash.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a production migration pending. Run from the terminal this command:
 `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

If there are no migrations pending, post more lines of the logs.

Comment: There is not a production migration pending.  If I visit the page and do heroku logs -t and then refresh the page, the log literally shows only 11 of those lines like I posted showing the 302 error.